Why should the precompiled header be earlier?
tmp0.h - precompiled header
#pragma once

#include <vector>

tmp0.cpp - creating a precompiled header
#include "tmp0.h"

main.cpp - main
#include <iostream>
#include "tmp0.h"

int main( void )
{
  std::cout << "Hello world";
  return 0;
}

The error:

error C2039: 'cout': is not a member of 'std'

If I swap the includes in places, it works correctly.
I don't understand why this is so.

When precompiled headers are enabled, Visual Studio compiler skips everything before #include directive that includes the precompiled header. This directive should be the first non-comment piece of code in the source file.

IMHO, precompiled headers are not worth the hassle for small to medium projects.  They don't save a lot of time and whenever a header file is changed, the precompiled header must be rebuilt (taking up time that it should be saving you).  Do without them, until the time it saves becomes significant.

Minor point: formally, the last line of output from a program should end with a newline. That rarely matters these days; it's a holdover from C on record-oriented mainframes used for business computing, which had to emulate output streams in a non-stream file system. But there's a modern-day reason, too: std::cout << "Hllo word"; can be confusing when you run your program from the command line and the output is Hilo word% because it's showing the command prompt immediately after the output. So std::cout << "Hllo word\n"; is preferable.

Unlike @ThomasMatthews, I think precompiled header should nearly always be used on Windows, except maybe on tiny single file projects. The Windows.h header, that is often needed in real projects, is a monster that takes several seconds to compile. On my experience, the build time on Windows / MSVC is roughly 10x smaller on typical projects with precompiled header.
